# Cant format sdcard other than ntfs - want ext2

Tags: 20.04, filesystem, sd-card

When i try to format 64gb sd card as ntfs it works fine but if I try ext3 or ext2 creating the file system will take hours and it throws IO error when saving superblocks, Tried multiple sdcards all behave the same. How to make it happen?

Comment: Why ext2 and ext3. The standard is now ext4. What do you want to put on the card? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4

Comment: For heroic launcher on steamdeck i need a filesystem that will support symlinks- Heroic is trying to link to proton and font files(etc.) and failing on ntfs. Will try ext4.

Comment: install the f3 package (fight fake flash) and check your cards.